# Wagtail return 301 or 404 status code instead of the default 410 for unpublished pages

Tags: wagtail

Wagtail returns the default 410 status code when the page is unpublished. Is there a way to return 301 status code with redirect or just 404 for unpublished pages?

The reason is as follows:

> Since Google still treats 404 and 410 errors differently, you need
> to use the 410 code only when you know for sure that the page has been deleted and
> will not return. This response is cached by default, the search robot
> no longer visits the page, and it, in turn, is removed from the index.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I get a 404 on an unpublished page when I test locally. Are you using the Wagtail API, or do you have some intermediate caching or middleware setup, perhaps?

Comment: @gasman
Okay, maybe.
But  in some cases I get 410 when I try to open a page that is deleted or unpublished. I need to return 301 instead of 410

Comment: I get a 404 on an unpublished page.  You can set up your 301 redirect under Settings -> Redirects.